# Google AppScript keeps returning "Exception: Event start time must be before event end time" error

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to import all the events on my google Calendar from April 1st,2023 to April 30, 2023.

I have tried the following query in google appscript, but getting an Exception error: Event Start time must be before event end time.

```
function getEvent() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("********@gmail.com");
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("4/1/2023 12:00 AM"), new Date("4/30/2024 11:59PM"));
  for(var i =0;i<events.length;i++){
    var title = events[i].getTitle();
    console.log(title);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getEvent() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("id");
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(2023,3,1,0,0,0), new Date(2023,3,30,23,59,0));
  for(var i =0;i<events.length;i++){
    var title = events[i].getTitle();
    console.log(title);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. Really appreciate the help. Still very new at this :(

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are messing the format of the end time Date, because you wrote "11:00PM" together. Just leave a space between the hour and the PM and should work.

```
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("4/1/2023 12:00 AM"), new Date("4/30/2024 11:59 PM"));
```

Comment: What a stupid mistake to make. Thank you for looking into it. Really appreciate the help. Still very new at this :(